# "Never use CRUD function names in URIs", Why?

Tags: api, uri, naming-conventions

Never use CRUD function names in URIs Why?

I was reading this [article about resource naming](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/#:%7E:text=Never%20use%20CRUD%20function%20names,which%20CRUD%20function%20is%20performed.) and they say that:

> 2.4. Never use CRUD function names in URIs

And I wondered why should I never use CRUD function names in URIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because (as the article says) it's redundant; the operation to perform is already identified by the HTTP request method POST, GET, PUT or DELETE which correspond to *Create*, *Read*, *Update* and *Delete* respectively.